# truncated Manhattan plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, p-value

I am trying to plot my p-values and make Manhattan plots, using the mhtplot.trunc from the gap library. Reason for using this package is that my p-values are too low to be plot in R (below e-308), and R just gives me the zeroes instead of real p-values when I pass this threshold. I need these plots to be accurate since it's for my paper, I can't just plot zeroes instead of real p-values.
Mhtplot.trunc should be able to handle the low p-values, but I keep running into the errors here.
Could anyone help me?

```
> library(gap)
> mhtplot.trunc(df, chr="Chromosome", bp="Position", p="P.value",
+               snp="MarkerName",
+               suggestiveline=FALSE, genomewideline=-log10(5e-8),
+               y.brk1=115, y.brk2=200, trunc.yaxis=TRUE, 
+               col = c("blue4", "skyblue")
+ )
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

All columns are numerical, except for the MarkerName.
I really need help here, any advice is welcome!

Comment: If your software tells you that $p=10^{-308}$, I would recommend that you first make sure that this output is a "real p-value". This is quite probably a floor value that should be treated as "lowest possible value", e.g., with complete separation.

Comment: This is the floor value for R, indeed. However, the real value in the output of METAL meta-analysis software which I used for creating my p-value files, is E-700. Values this low are common when working with such a large study sample as mine. So I want to plot the real p-values, I don't think the reviewers will be fine with me saying "R cannot plot my p-values" :)

Comment: A p-value that small is so sensitive to your modeling assumptions that it is pointless to render it precisely.  It should suffice to group all sufficiently small p-values (where "sufficiently" depends on your application and the audience) into one bin of "essentially zero" values and plot them as such.  The only kind of reason I can imagine for trying to compute them to such precision would be if you are studying the computational algorithm and these results provide useful information about that -- but that's a problem about numerical algorithms, not statistical analysis.